# How to create a rectangle with two rounded corners across the top?

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-rect

How do I make two rounded cornered rectangle at the top left edge and top right edge preferably as an SVG rectangle?

Is the only way to do this is to convert the rectangle to a path?

The reason I do NOT want to use a path is because if I set the width of the path to 100% the path is distorted. If I set the width of a rectangle to 100% the rectangle is NOT distorted but it doesn’t support individual corner radius.

What can I do?

Comment: Does it need to be SVG or can you use a div with border-radius?

Comment: @cam I know how to make a div with border radius but you can add that as an alternative answer. I’m really trying to get confirmation that it’s not possible with the SVG Rect which would make the alternative answer viable.

Comment: Can someone reopen this? It’s not a duplicate

Comment: No, the duplicate answer is correct; Can't be done with a ``rect``, you have to create the effect with a ``path``. Robert Longson really knows SVG, if he says it can't be done, it can't be done.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Ok then let him answer here saying it can’t be fine in SVG so that others can see the answer

Comment: That answer is in the _duplicate_ link. If StackOverflow was built your way it would have 167 questions all giving the same answer.

Comment: What *android* are you talking about? I don't understand your edit

Comment: @TemaniAfif There was a question with nearly the same exact title but it was tagged for Google Android, not for SVG

Answer (score -1):

Try wrapping up your svg into a div and then give border-top-right-radius and border-top-left-radius to whatever value you want to have round corners on top.